# Can JSTL or Custom Tag Libraries be Called from Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, thymeleaf, jstl, jsp-tags

Can we call JSTL or Custom Tag Libraries from inside of Thymeleaf?

We have numerous tags that we have built over the years and would prefer to not transform them to Thymeleaf Fragments.